# Match all except specific group

Tags: regex

I have a test string `repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz` and I want to exclude `2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz` from that string and match everything else. Digits with date and hour can be different. String at the beginning of text can be any word, can contain digits, dashes or underscores. Constant characters are:

- dash between repo name and date
- `.gz` at end of text

I tried following regex:

```
^.*(?!-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.gz$)
```

but it always matches whole text

Comment: What does `Digits with date and hour can be different.` mean? Can the format be different from the format you currently match? If so, can you update the question with the possible formats?

Comment: no, format will be always same but date can be different.

Comment: Did you test the patterns? What is the tool or language?

Comment: yes, it works fine in online testers but I have problem with sed to make substitution. If I use `echo "repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz" | sed -r 's/^([\w-]+)-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.gz$/\1/p'` it always prints full string.

Comment: Do yo mean like this? `echo "repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz" | sed -En 's/^([[:alnum:]-]+)-[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}\.gz$/\1/p'`

Comment: YES!! thx :D I dunno why `sed` is not working with proper regex syntax

Comment: Because it is a different variant. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202219/how-to-use-w-in-regular-expression-in-sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `^.*(?!-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.gz$)` always matches the whole text because `.*` will first match until the end of the string. Then at the end of the string, it will assert that what is directly on the right is not the date like pattern.

That assertion will succeed as it is at the end of the string.

---

You could use a capturing group with a character class matching word characters or a hyphen and use that in the replacement:

```
^([\w-]+)-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.gz$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BTcguu/1)

If the beginning can not start with an underscore and can not contain consecutive underscores, you could repeat matching a hyphen and a word character in a grouping stucture `\w+(?:-\w+)*`

```
^(\w+(?:-\w+)*)-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.gz$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N1pSRF/1)